# GBQ: rewrite table with a POST request

Tags: google-bigquery

Exploring [Loading data to GBQ with POST request](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request)  I haven't found how to rewrite existing table (current examples append data to existing table or create new table if it doesn't exist). I see that there is a possibility to do it with web console so I assume there is a way to resolve this task with POST request. Are there someone who knows it?

Comment: Just add to the job configuration the relevant section even if it's not mentioned in the samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `WRITE_TRUNCATE` value for [`configuration.load.writeDisposition`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.writeDisposition) property of job configuration

> configuration.load.writeDisposition   string  [Optional] Specifies the action that occurs if the destination table already exists.
>
> The following values are supported:
>   **WRITE_TRUNCATE**: If the table already exists, BigQuery overwrites the table data. 
>   **WRITE_APPEND**: If the table already exists, BigQuery appends the data to the table. 
>   **WRITE_EMPTY**: If the table already exists and contains data, a 'duplicate' error is returned in the job result.
>   The default value is WRITE_APPEND.
>
> Each action is atomic and only occurs if BigQuery is able to complete the job successfully. Creation, truncation and append actions occur as one atomic update upon job completion.

Comment: have no enough 'reputation' for voting yet but I get your point, thanks